# What does points score do in Hitman Absolution?

Tags: hitman-absolution

I just play the game and was wondering what does point do in this game ? Are they just a number to compare to another player online or maybe you can buy or unlock any stuff in game ?

Answer (score 1):

High scores obtained in main singleplayer campaign missions unlock "assasin techniques" which upgrade Agents 47's abilities (improving recovery time, reducing weapon recoil). You can find a list of all assasin techniques [here](http://hitman.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin_Techniques).